# Convertir query de SQL en str Python

Tags: python, mysql

estoy teniendo un problema. Estoy leyendo unos datos de mi base de datos en MySQL desde python. El problema que tengo es que los datos los obtengo como una tupla.
Y necesito convertir esos datos a un str, para hacer una segunda consulta.

Esta seria mi consulta

```
consulta = "SELECT id_articulo FROM articulos WHERE tipo_articulo = %s AND talle = %s " \
                   "AND marca = %s AND material = %s"
        sql_cursor.execute(consulta, (tipo, talle, marca, material))
        aux = sql_cursor.fetchall()
```

El dato que obtengo en `aux` es una tupla, y despues no puedo usar ese dato para hacer otra consulta en sql por que es una tupla.

¿Alguna forma de pasar ese dato a un str?

Comment: Hola Fernando, puedes por favor mostrar como es el resultado de `aux` que tienes actualmente y como te gustaría que fuese?

Comment: El resultado es una tupla `(1,)` yo necesito sacar ese 1 como un string

Answer (score 1):

`fetchall()` retorna una lista de filas, cada fila es una tupla, cada elemento de la tupla es el valor en una columna de esa fila. En tu ejemplo pareciera estar retornando una única fila con una única columna, algo así `[(1,)]` para acceder de forma individual al dato:

```
id = str(aux[0][0]) # Desempaqueto primer fila y primer columna
```

De una forma más genérica si tuvieras más filas, podrías hacer algo así:

```
rows = sql_cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    for col in row:
        print(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bien despues de romperme un poco la cabeza, revise el tipo de dato que devolvia la consulta con `print(type(aux))`
En principio devolvia una lista, agregando un indice en el primer valor de la lista habia una tupla, utilizando `replace` y sabiendo el indice de la lista.

Hice esta funcion, quizas no es la más efectiva, y hay una forma más eficiente de solucionar el problema.

```
def tuplastring(tupla):
    tupla = "".join(str(tupla[0]))
    aux2 = tupla.replace("(", "")
    aux3 = aux2.replace(")", "")
    aux4 = aux3.replace(",", "")
    tupla = aux4
    return tupla
```

Lo que hace es convertir la tupla en un string, como los string en python son inmutables, se necesita trabajar desde otra variable, con `replace` elimino los parentesis `( )` de la tupla y la `,`, y devuelvo el string con el formato que necesito para hacer otra consulta en SQL.